# Can a browser window/tab target be (re)named?

Tags: html

I'd like a hyperlink on a page to open its site's landing page, in a new tab if it's not already open, or, if it is already open to have the browser switch to that tab.

My idea for this was to use the target attribute but the problem is that the tab for the landing page doesn't have a name that I can refer to.

So my question is, can a tab be named by the page loaded in it so that it can be referred to by the target attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, **no**.

However, if you open a child "window" with JavaScript, you can retain a handle to that window and modify things that way.

In general, browsers control the behavior of how a link opens. Some default to open in the same viewport, others default to a new tab, and still others default to a new window entirely.

The best thing to do, however, is to *not* try to control this and instead allow the browser (and more importantly, the *user*) to decide how the clicked link should be opened. This allows your power users to control how they use your site, and at the same time keeps the behavior of the browser consistent for your users, which is a *critical* component in keeping your users happy.

Comment: +1 I was just about to state how trying to make things work this way would go against what a user is comfortable with and used to.  I know when I click on a link with the middle mouse it will open in a new tab, I would not want it to just switch to an open tab if I really want two tabs open for that site.  It would cause a lot of frustration if to get a second tab of the site I would have to copy the address to a new blank tab instead of just being able to click the link again.

Comment: @jzworkman - Yes. As a "power user", I often want things to behave a certain way because I might have a bajillion tabs open already or want to open something up in the background so I can come back to it later without interrupting my current flow. Sites that don't do as I tell them to irritate me and I quickly stop using those sites altogether.

Comment: Exactly, the site needs to work like every other site I am used to in terms of base functionality.  Dont make a link that does something different than every other link on the internet(now I just hope the OP reads these)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and I agree completely with your sentiments. It drives me crazy to no end when I don't get the expected behaviour, a still I was considering this. Thanks for reminding me.